# nginx - phppgadmin - *1 access forbidden by rule

Tags: php, postgresql, nginx, phppgadmin

I want to setup phppgadmin, postgresql is already - done by following [this article](http://www.unixmen.com/install-postgresql-and-phppgadmin-on-debian-7-wheezy/)

but I have nginx,

I did so far these configs:

```
ln -s /usr/share/phppgadmin /var/www
```

and

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/phppgadmin`:

```
server{
    listen 85;
    server_name     pgadmin.mypage.com;
    root            /var/www/phppgadmin;
    index index.html index.html index.php;

    access_log      /var/log/phppgadmin/access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/phppgadmin/error.log;

    location / {
            allow   my_page_IP;
            deny    all;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/phppgadmin$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
 }
```

and

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/phppgadmin /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

and

```
service nginx restart
```

but I am getting:

```
403 Forbidden
```

the error.log says:

```
2015/03/21 18:06:14 [error] 16916#0: *1 access forbidden by rule, client: 188.194.97.247, server: pgadmin.mypage.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "my_page_IP:85"
```

I did:

```
chmod -R 775 phppgadmin/ 
chown -R www-data:www-data phppgadmin/
```

but still the same 403 message. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bump up your debug level and confirm which location block is matching.  My guess is it's not the one you think. ;)

Comment: @lukepeterson yep, deny part was wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

Access forbidden by rule mean that the access of the desired page was dropped by rule you have put in your configuration.

Just try to remove rule on each location to see which is cause problem.